# How do I perform spatial logistic regression in SAS?

Tags: sas, geospatial, logistic-regression, prediction

I am trying to develop a spatiotemporal logistic regression model to predict the presence/absence of a disease in U.S. counties (contiguous U.S.) based on climatologic variables, with data points for each year between 2007 and 2014; ideally, I would like a model with functionality to score additional datasets, e.g., use the model developed for 2006-2014 to predict disease probability in future climate scenarios.  The model needs to account for spatial autocorrelation, and (again, ideally) repeated measures (each county has one data point per year).  Unfortunately, my SAS abilities are not up to the task.  Would anyone have suggestions for developing the model? The data, in csv format, take the form of:

countyFIPS  year   outcome   predictor1   predictor2   predictor3   latitude   longitude

where

countyFIPS = unique 5-digit identifier for U.S. counties
outcome = at least one case in the county for the given year, coded 0/1
latitude and longitude denote the centroid of the county

I'm really bad at this, so please be gentle and use small words...

Comment: https://communities.sas.com/t5/SAS-Statistical-Procedures/How-do-I-perform-spatial-logistic-regression/m-p/302454 Same poster I presume? Can you point to a reference for spatial logistic regression?

Comment: Yup, same poster--trying to cast as wide a net as possible.  The best reference I can come up with is the slrm procedure in R.